# PHP Cookies contains Less data

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, laravel-5

I used https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie to set cookies. When I check in browser, cookies are set properly but When I extract cookies on server side(PHP) it behaves abnormally. Sometimes `$_COOKIE` contains/holds all the content/data which is normal & fine, but sometimes `$_COOKIE` misses some of the cookie data that is being set in from client side.
[image: Screenshot of request & response]

You can see in screenshot that `sub-total` & `laravel_session` keys are missing in response when I print it in PHP while both are present in request header

I am using Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies size is limited to about 4000 bytes ( including key, value, expiration date). you probably exceeded the limit, and your data was cut off.

You can increase the size by changing the value of `LimitRequestFieldSize` in your apache conf file.

keep in mind that generally, storing so much data in cookies is a sign of bad design, maybe try using `session` or `local storage` instead.